# Can a Italo "booking contact" be counted as any other category than Adult?

Tags: trains, bookings

I have booked a Italo Più train between Milano Centrale and Bologna.

I am counted as a `Young` regarding their age guidelines. However, I am the person booking the ticket and traveling with an `Adult`.

Looking at the ticket, I (the `Young`) am classified as `Adult`, and my travel mate is classified as a `Young` (where they would largely qualify into `Adult`).

I know this can't be reversed online, and by making a mock booking, It is clear a *booking contact* can't be anything other than an `Adult`, and only further passengers can be counted as other age categories.

I don't think their customer support (Phone-only) is available in any other language than Italian, which I don't speak (and it is tolled, which I would like to avoid).

I suspect I will have issues with that booking when boarding, has anyone encountered that issue before?

Comment: It's very likely that, as long as the fare for the both of you is correct, and you're occupying the assigned seats, nobody will care. I've never been asked an ID on Italian trains, even tough the e-ticket says I must show one together with the PNR.

Comment: Railways aren't interested in who is travelling. They just want to make sure everyone has paid.